# NDK build error - LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am getting below error while building.

```
mobi@mobi-H81M-DS2:~$ cd workspace/MasterX/jni/

mobi@mobi-H81M-DS2:~workspace/MasterX/jni/$ "/home/mobi/Android/Ndk/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build"
Android NDK: ERROR:/home/mobi/workspace/MasterX/jni/libsndfile/Android.mk:sndfile-prebuilt: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
Android NDK: Check that /home/mobi/workspace/MasterX/jni/libsndfile/arm64-v8a/libsndfile.so exists  or that its path is correct   
/home/mobi/Android/Ndk/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
mobi@mobi-H81M-DS2:~workspace/MasterX/jni/$
```

Can any body tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: Please include the contents of your Android.mk file in the question.

Comment: The errors make the problem sufficiently clear; rather than the Android.mk, what would be useful to know would be the intention, ie, was building for 64-bit ARM a goal, in which case it needs to happen for the library as well, or was it simply a result of inheriting a modern "build everything" project setup.

Answer (score 1):

> Check that 
>   /home/mobi/workspace/MasterX/jni/libsndfile/arm64-v8a/libsndfile.so
>   exists  or that its path is correct

To literally resolve this complaint, you would need to place a 64-bit ARM version of your prebuilt library in the listed location.

Did you mean to build for 64-bit ARM (by including it on on your ABI list or telling it to build all ABIs)?  If so, you will need to provide versions of all your prebuilts matching this ABI, and any others you request.

It looks like libsndfile.so is probably the output of building *someone's android port of* [the libsndfile project](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) from source with the Android NDK, so you can repeat that for 64 bit ARM.  You should be able to do this, because the library is under the LGPL license, which effectively means that you cannot use it if you do not have the corresponding source and build scripts available to fulfill your license obligations.  Hopefully it will be as simple as adding 64-bit ARM to the ABI list for whatever Android NDK adaption of that project's build system you used.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, let me try it

Comment: I downloaded source code and tried to follow "readme" to compile source code.
Can you please tell me how can i get .so files for each version?

Comment: It's not clear that the primary upstream source supports android.  You should make an LGPL sources request to whoever you got the 32-bit arm .so from for their android-adapted source *and build script* which you can modify to include the 64-bit ABI.